# How to fix Windows driver StartService error 1275

Tags: windows, driver

I wrote the following driver for windows 10:

```
#include <ntddk.h>

void SampleUnload(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DriverObject);
}

extern "C"
NTSTATUS
DriverEntry(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DriverObject);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistryPath);

    DriverObject->DriverUnload = SampleUnload;

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now I want to test the driver in a seperate Windows 10 virtual machine (VirtualBox).

There I set the machine in the test signing mode with the following command as administrator
and rebooted the system:

```
bcdedit /set testsigning on
```

After installation of the driver with:

```
sc create sample type= kernel binPath= z:\Sample.sys
```

and starting it with:

```
sc start sample
```

The error 1275 occours

My approach was to install the Windows SDK and WDK, but it did not work.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

To check the meaning of an error code, use the windows error lookup tool. (In visual studio select tools/error lookup).
For the error code 1275, it says : "This driver has been blocked from loading."

So I am guessing your bcdedit command to allow loading an unsigned driver did not work.
There is some discussion on how to do that here:http://maxedtech.com/about-testmode/.

The other possibility coming to mind is that your driver is not signed at all. This MS documentation page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/the-testsigning-boot-configuration-option says:

> The operating system loader and the kernel load drivers that are signed by any certificate. The certificate validation is not required to chain up to a trusted root certification authority. However, each driver image file must have a digital signature.

Comment: The driver seems to be signed by vs2019:
1>Building 'Sample' with toolset 'WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0' and the 'Desktop' target platform.
1>Quelle.cpp
1>Sample.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Pall\source\repos\Sample\Debug\Sample.sys
1>Done Adding Additional Store
1>Successfully signed: C:\Users\Pall\source\repos\Sample\Debug\Sample.sys
Additionally Windows 10 says in the right down corner that it is in testmode

Comment: How about the os vs driver compatiblity? If your OS is 64 bit, you need to build the driver for x64, and a win32 build is required for 32-bit os.

Comment: I changed the platform to x64 and the target OS to Windows 10

Comment: No, the problem still exists

Comment: I'm running out of suggestions... did you update the driver in z:\ after changing the build target to x64? Maybe windows is still trying to load the 32-bit version?

Comment: Also, try loading the driver from c:\ instead of z:, especially if z: is a network or removable drive.

Comment: I updated the driver after every new build and copied the driver to the Download folder. But it did not help

Comment: "The download folder" still sounds a bit fishy. Try copying it to e.g. c:\windows\ and loading it from there. Also note, that since you switched the build target to x64, the .sys file is probably created in a different directory than before.

Comment: I checked the directory explicitly and tried to load the driver from C:, no success.
Can the secureboot be a problem in the VirtualBox?

Comment: Thank you very much

I found a solution for the problem.

I had to use the "konfiguration manager" in the project properties of VisualStudio.
There I activated the points "release" and the Platform "x64"

Now it works